# Disable ng-click on certain conditions of application for all types of element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

In my application I've binded several elements with ng-click directive like below

```
<a ng-click="DoSomething()"/>
<button ng-click="DoSomethingElse()">xyz</button>
<span ng-click="DoSomething()"></span>
```

Now in my application in certain scenarios I want default behavior of ng-click to happen, but in certain scenarios I want to completely disable the callback function(DoSomething(), DoSomethingElse()..) to be called..

For checking this scenarios I've one scope variable say `$scope.IsClickEnable = true/false;`

So how can I accomplish this kind of behaviour?

I can use ng-disable to disable elements but it will only work on button kind of elements, so that will not work in my scenario

And I can also check conditions in every function call but I want more specific way to accomplish this by overriding ng-click behavior or something..

Comment: Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava It will not work on all types of elements

Comment: Have a look to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353385/angularjs-want-to-disable-the-link-when-it-clicked-once

Answer (score 75):

Do like this:

```
<button ng-click="!IsClickEnable||DoSomethingElse()">xyz</button>
```

when the value of IsClickEnable is true then the function will be called on the button click then the function 'DoSomethingElse()' will be called else it will not get called

Comment: There is also some another syntax like this <button ng-click="IsClickEnable?DoSomethingElse():null">xyz</button>.  IsClickEnable is true then the function will be called

Comment: For readability I think it is easier to write it like this <button ng-click="IsClickEnable && DoSomethingElse()">xyz</button>