# How to disable all ng-click and ng-submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

is there any way, how can I globally (in service) disable and enable all ng-click and ng-submit events?

For example when user is offline I want to disable all actions till he gets connection back..

I tried to bind all elements with an onClick event which will call stopImmediatePropagation but it didn't work..

```
    $('*[ng-click]').click(function( event ) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

Also this question is a little bit different from this one:
[Disable ng-click on certain conditions of application for all types of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194477/disable-ng-click-on-certain-conditions-of-application-for-all-types-of-element)

I'd like to disable/enable all events in APP globally from service, I'm not able to modify all ng-* calls on all elements in the APP..

Comment: this should be done at document level. Try: `$(document).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});`

Comment: Tried, but no difference.. ng-click event handler is called before this one..

Comment: write a decorator for `ngClick` directive ... http://briantford.com/blog/angular-hacking-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I end up with temporarily **disabling all events on the page** using jquery..
I got inspired from this plugin http://ignitersworld.com/lab/eventPause.html which for some reason did not work (without any error)

So I took main parts and put it to this class which is working now **using jquery v2.1.1**:

```
var EventManager = function() {
    var self = this;
    var nullFun=function(){};

    var getIndex = function(array,value){
        for(var i=0; i< array.length; i++){
            if(array[i]==value){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;  
    };

    this.pauseEvent = function(elm,eventAry){
        var events = $._data(elm, "events");

        if (events) {
            $.each(events, function(type, definition) {
                if((getIndex(eventAry,type)!=-1)||(eventAry=='')){
                    $.each(definition, function(index, event) {
                        if (event.handler.toString() != nullFun.toString()){
                            if(!$._iwEventPause) $._iwEventPause = {};

                            $._iwEventPause["iw-event" + event.guid] = event.handler;
                            event.handler = nullFun;
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    };

    this.activeEvent = function(elm,eventAry){
        var events = $._data(elm, "events");
        if (events) {
            $.each(events, function(type, definition) {
                if((getIndex(eventAry,type)!=-1)||(eventAry=='')){
                    $.each(definition, function(index, event) {
                        if (event.handler.toString() == nullFun.toString()){
                            event.handler = $._iwEventPause["iw-event" + event.guid];
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    };

    this.disableAll = function(el) {
        el = el || $('*');
        el.each(function() {
            self.pauseEvent($(this)[0], '');
        });
        self.pauseEvent($(window)[0], '');
    };

    this.enableAll = function(el) {
        el = el || $('*');
        el.each(function() {
            self.activeEvent($(this)[0], '');
        });
        self.activeEvent($(window)[0], '');
    };

    return this;    
};

var eManager = new EventManager();

eManager.disableAll();
eManager.enableAll();
```

This will go through window object and all elements on the page, move their event handlers away to _iwEventPause object and replace handlers with dummy function.. When enabling, it will move handlers back so they get normally called..

This solution does not handle event handlers added after disabling..

Answer (score 1):

Try including a `return false` too:

```
$('*[ng-click]').click(function( event ) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return false;
});
```

**Snippet**

The below snippet demonstrates that multiple event handlers attached to a single `<a>` works too.

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
    alert("Hello!");
    return false;
  });
  $("a").click(function () {
    alert("Bye!");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: Tried, but it is still not working.. It looks like ng-click event handler is called before this one..